# If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a $\Bbb{V}$ and $\Bbb{U} \subseteq \Bbb{V}$ then $\exists\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ basis for $\Bbb{U}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $\Bbb{U}$ is a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $\Bbb{V}$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{\vec{v}_1,..,\vec{v}_n\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb{V}$, then some subset of $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\Bbb{U}$

Comment: This is not really a question and as a statement it's wrong. A counterexample is $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ but no subset of it is a basis of $\langle(1,1)\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Think about $V = \mathbb{R}^2;$ if $\mathcal{B}$ is any basis for $V$, then there are exactly $4$ spaces spanned by subsets of $\mathcal{B}$.

There are infinitely many subspaces, though. (Lines through $0$.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Let $V=\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathcal B=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$. Consider the subspace generated by $(1,1)$.